# How can I earn the Deputy Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

Figured that this question would be on meta already, but I can't find it. The description for the badge says "Achieved maximum flag-weight by flagging appropriately".

I aspire to achieve maximum flag-weight, how can I accomplish this goal?

This badge has recently been awarded to users all across the rep spectrum.

Comment: Related post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight - there hasn't been flag weight in years

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag comments, answer or question that needs moderator attention. Remember that when you flag for bad reason (eg.: I disagree with the post) your flag weight will decrease.

A good place to start is https://stackoverflow.com/review/ This section aggregates question and answer that match certain pattern which are known to have a potential of bad content. If you take a look at it you can find stuff that needs to be flagged.