# We don't need (to see) flag weight!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-weight

#### Update

[A new feature was added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85151/how-to-read-the-flagging-summary), but there appears to be no documentation out there. The change in flag weight caused by each flagging still missing.

#### TL;DR:

Flag weight is **not very clear**. Just telling the user how many flags got **approved/rejected** would increase the flagging behavior. Additionally, **flag feedback** could improve this even more.

#### Question:

[Flag weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) is shown on a User's profile as a number between 0 and 750, each user starts with 100. The problem is that after reaching 500, flag weight increases in a sub-linear fashion, and it becomes hard to tell how many flags were considered to be correct or incorrect.

I find it easy to remember "I am at 250" and when I come back, discover "I am at 280", so I had 3 flags approved.

Nowadays, "I am at 576.3529". When I view my profile tomorrow, I'll be at 577.1285 or something, but I won't know how many flags got approved, denied or were ignored.

- Would "10 flags approved, 3 flags denied, 2 flags pending" not provide **more useful information**? Even if it's just a pop-up box (StackExchange seems to use span-title for that).
- Additionally, being able to see what flags were denied would **provide feedback to the user that is flagging** in a way not desired by the moderator(s), and improve the flagging quality.

Maybe we can click on the flag weight to see a **page with all our flags**, the status (approved/denied/pending), the moderator that reviewed the flag, and maybe a comment the moderator left to explain why the flag was denied?

Comment: Because of the sublinear thing, if your flag weight went up you can be pretty sure they were all approved. I'm over 700 now and I think having 42 flags approved would give me less gain than the loss from having one flag denied.

Comment: I had high hopes for this proposal when I read the title...

Comment: @Grace the only game where the score is not shown is the Russian roulette

Comment: Well, flag weight was never a priority for me, but somehow I'm sad to see it go.  RIP, flag weight.

Comment: I gained  [this much flag weight](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_BM-na2bPSBI/TKpmnFlEL2I/AAAAAAAAAHc/0YCtuDhqebo/s1600/homer-simpson-muumuu1.jpg) and now it's all for naught! :'-(

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Fine, I removed flag weight. It is gone.

Instead you now see a count of helpful flags you raised on your user profile. You can see this number on anybody else's profile as well.

This number can be clicked to give you a breakdown of how we counted it, only when viewing your own profile.

The 2 badges [Deputy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/badges/140/deputy) and [Marshal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/badges/160/marshal) were adjusted, however we did not strip any old granted badges.

Comment: The peasants rejoice! Please mark [my request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106627/160166) as status-completed too

Comment: Questions! I have them. Since comment flags are now included in the breakdown, do they count for the adjusted badges? Also, does that mean they'll show up in the flagging history? Only I appear to have a declined comment flag and I'd like to see what it was.

Comment: "Fine, I removed flag weight. It is gone." - Well you don't have to sound so happy about it =)

Comment: Oh, and the † footnote for disputed flags seems to have evaporated.

Comment: @lunboks ... they always did count for the badges, and they continue to count ... the text is "raised 80 helpful flags"

Comment: @lunboks flag weight is no longer a concept end users need to worry about

Comment: I enjoyed watching my flag weight go up by a fraction of a point. :/

Comment: Now that the fear of getting a declined flag is gone, prepare for 100x more flags to litter your queue!

Comment: Thanks! **It is more clear this way**, but you didn't need to remove the negative impact for flagging wrongfully. Maybe add a counter to "unhelpful" flags as well? ;]

Comment: @Konerak gross unhelpful flagging is abuse, the vast majority of people flag helpfully, if people game this to get a badge they will be dealt with

Comment: Aww. Yesterday evening I went over the 740-threshold on SO and I somehow felt pride. I already was preparing mentally for watching the flag weight to go up in fractions of hundredths. This morning I got the Marshal-badge... - While I enjoy getting a gold badge, I feel a bit sad that it came in this fast. And now for the next badge! :)

Comment: So, it appears that spam flags that result in an automatically deleted post now *don't* count as helpful. Is that right?

Comment: @lunboks I have reported the † footnote for disputed flags as a bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119740/the-footnote-for-disputed-flags-is-missing-in-the-revised-flagging-history

Comment: After overcoming the initial "Eeeeeek!" reaction to the change on my profile, this does seem to be a clearer concept. Nice change.

Comment: I like everything about this except for the part where I went from needing 7 more helpful flags to get a Deputy badge to 63.  Eeeeeeek!

Comment: @mootinator agree, we should use more confusing numbers for our badges ... copy editor should require 493 edits and so on ...

Comment: No, no @waffles this is me whining that you didn't convert my 430 flag weight into at least 33 helpful flags (instead of the 17 the database knows about) since I got half of that score before it was being tracked.  *sob* etc.  I promise to get over it.  Sending me a StackOverflow mug wouldn't hurt the process either.  Just saying.

Comment: @mootinator my 730+ flag weight is now a "31 helpful" as 400+ of the flags I have submitted were before the helpful/unhelpful bit was added.  You can imagine how thrilled I am with this change :-( I'm not even sure what the benefit is, as previously you could just click on the flag weight to find your number of helpful flags...

Comment: @waffles can you tell since when comment helpful flags count toward the deputy badge?

Comment: @waffles But I do worry about it, because for a low-weight (new) user on SO it's almost impossible to get your (duplicate) flags even being reviewed! Specifically, I would like to know my place in this crazy 5k queue.

Answer (score 16):

You can now view a detailed log of your flagging history by clicking on your flag weight in your profile. The url is `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<uid>` . I guess this closes this matter.

Comment: Thanks. [Someone asked for explanation of this new feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85151/how-to-read-the-flagging-summary), but there appears to be no documentation out there. **The change in flag weight caused by each flagging still missing.**

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you need to *know* how many flags were approved? If you did need to know that, you'd get a history of your flags and whether or not they were dismissed valid or invalid.

Comment: Knowing how many tags were approved gives some pointers on how good job you are doing. I think introducing flag weight (or counters, as proposed here) was really good idea. Before that flagging was completely black box, which sucks, and eats motivation to do so from many people, including myself.

Comment: @Olli Sure, so why do you want this score hidden exactly?

Comment: Errr. I did not say that I want it to be hidden. Please read whole question instead of just title. Flag weight is sublinear after 500 - you can't know what's happening. Before that it's somewhat useful. But "10 flags approved, 3 flags denied, 2 flags pending" is much more useful for following what is happening with your flags.