# Allow me to see my “bad” flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-weight

I can now view all my mod flags and see what action was taken – however this is not very useful to me.  (The list is long and I can’t tell if no action has been taken by a mod, or if a mod has not looked at the flag yet)

I wish to be able to see all of my mod flags that the mods did **not** find useful, so I can learn to flag better.

Comment: This is a subquestion of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight, no?

Comment: Being able to filter by action taken (deleted, comment added, etc.) would help solve this problem.

Comment: @marcog, provided I can filter between "no action taken" and "not looked at"

Comment: I think it's safe to say that any flag older than a day or so is very unlikely to be "not looked at", so even without this information filtering would be sufficient to learn about our bad flagging practices. But yes, it would be a nice addition.