# Show current flag weight on flag weight summary page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-weight

The flag weight summary page shows my name, rep, and badges. But not my flag weight. Could we add this?

Comment: For anyone else finding this and wondering why their flag summary page doesn't show it when this says `status-completed`, it's because [flag weight is dead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight/119709#119709).

Answer (score 6):

Totally agree with that. It can then become a true tracking panel that show you all you review and I won't have to go back to profile to check on flag increase/decrease.