# The footnote for disputed flags is missing in the revised flagging history

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-history

Since [flag weight was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119709/163868) there remains a dagger (†) to mark a footnote for disputed flags in the flagging history:

[image: Flagging history on Stack Overflow]

I understand this as a bug. Either the dagger marking a footnote should be removed or the footnote should be added. It is only confusing to mark a footnote but include a footnote. The user will wonder what the dagger means.

Here are further examples to show that it is confusing:

[image: Flagging history on TeX.SX]

[image: Flagging history on Ask Ubuntu]

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment As a web developer I'm used to people crying wolf for something being a couple of pixels off. :) Other than that, wish granted. I think it was the shouting that did the trick :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed in trunk, will be deployed next round.